# Does rosdep support installing dependencies from PPAs?

Tags: ros, rosdep, apt, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a fresh post regarding the question raised [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9151/is-it-possible-to-have-rosdep-set-up-a-ubuntu-ppa-on-your-system-as-part-of-dependency-validation/).

Basically, I'd like to know if installing ROS package dependencies from a third-party apt repository is supported/recommended. I understand that non-debian users would still need to install these packages from source.

I see at least one third-party apt repository added in the rosdistro/rosdep/base.yaml, see [lines 540-552](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L540-L552)

However, based on the discussion [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11879/best-practice-for-rosdep-ubuntu-packages-and-others/) , and REPS [111](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0111.html), [112](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0111.html) and [125](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0111.html) - I get the feeling that embedding bash commands and adding apt-repos in a rosdep.yaml is frowned upon.

What is the best way to add system dependencies from a third-party apt repository to a ROS package?

/daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70210/does-rosdep-support-installing-dependencies-from-ppas?/) by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep does not support adding repositories.  That's a significant scope creep as well as potentially having a significant unintended impact on a running system.  Right now the users are required to manually add the ROS repository, through this step they are changing the configuration of their machine.  If rosdep allowed adding arbitrary PPAs you could easily end up with PPAs which provided conflicting packages and the user would no longer have control or knowledge of what software sources they had enabled for their computer.

Adding new repositories to a sources list is something which should be vetted and known about by the user/administrator.  New repositories may contain more than just the packages you want, possibly including overriding existing packages on the system.

If you want to use another repository you should create your own rosdep rules file and add it to your rosdep sources.  And then instruct your users to add your repository to their apt sources before using the new rosdep rules.

This also would wreak havoc on the debian building pipeline as it would have to be able to support pulling packages from the union of all the repositories, and would need to sync all required external debians from the external repositories to be able to make packages installable, because anything built into a debian package should be installable from that specific repo.

Note this is why Ubuntu's general policy is that PPAs do not contain libraries, as it's not reproducible to have PPAs chaining.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-01**:
@dPackard As you mentioned the easiest way for you to get them in will be to bloom them.  We do syncronize a set of debian packages from upstream PPAs into the ROS repository, but usually that is only to support backports of upcoming Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is "acceptable practice", but I have noticed a few interesting rosdep definitions that include bash scripts to get a ppa, one example: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L550

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-01**:
Yeah, that's frowned upon.  We should clean that one up.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-03-07**:\

> We should clean that one up.

Done in https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/1668